# 403 forbidden after making a GET request though jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, http-status-code-403

I am trying to get users from base in Laravel on typeahead in search, but I am getting an error:

> jquery-2.2.0.min.js:4 GET https://...../master/users/searchresult?query=sy 403 (Forbidden)

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#userdatatable').DataTable();
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var path = "{{ url('/master/users/searchresult') }}";
  $('#search').typeahead({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function(query, process) {
      return $.get(path, {
        query: query
      }, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        return process(data);
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: 403 means that your request failed to authenticate. Check if you need to send some kind of basic/bearer auth token in a header.

Comment: Also note that your code is using jQuery 1.9.1, yet the error says 2.2.0. This is very odd. Check you're not including multiple versions of jQuery in the same page. In addition, both of those versions are now outdated. You should look to update to the latest version which at time of this comment is 3.6.0

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hi, I tried with    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    }); but still same. I am using Laravel 6

Comment: It's recommended to use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) with Laravel. By doing so you don't have to worry about sending the csrf token along anymore since axios does that for you. So if you're in no way required to use jQuery, switching to axios might help.